# Having multiple columns within a single row of TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to use `GridLayout`, to have 4 text views (different string length) being displayed as same size, within same row of `TableLayout`.

Here is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_label"
        android:layout_width="12dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:gravity="left"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                android:gravity="right"
            />       
        </TableRow>        

        <View android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />            

        <TableRow>
            <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/myGrid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"          
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            />

        </TableRow>  

    </TableLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

and here are my adapter code for the row of list view.

```
package org.yccheok.jstock.widget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.yccheok.jstock.activity.R;
import org.yccheok.jstock.portfolio.Order;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private ArrayList<Order> items;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
        }
        Order o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
            if (tt != null) {
                  tt.setText(o.getOrderName());                            
            }
            if (bt != null) {
                  bt.setText(o.getOrderStatus());
            }
        }


        GridView grid = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.myGrid);        
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getContext()));


        return v;
    }


    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textview = new TextView(mContext);
            textview.setText("Hello");
            return textview;
        }
    }    
}
```

However, I am getting pretty strange result. (Highlight in red)

[image]

What my expectation is something like this. (Highlight in red)

[image]

Does this mean I can't use `GridLayout` in the row of `TableLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the source of your problem or not, but I believe that all elements in a TableRow should be given a column number (e.g. android:layout_column="1").